# Remove list of files from different subfolders

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

I have a folder (call "folder"), composed of different subfolders ("subfolder1", "subfolder2",...). I would like to remove a list of files in all the subfolder of "folder", while some files are present in all the subfolders!

I currently use :

`while read file; do rm "$file"basz.dat; done < ~/folder/subfolder1/list.txt`

Unfortunately this do the job just for the current folder. How can I apply the same command to all the subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
while read file;do find . -type f -name "$file"basz.dat -delete; done < list.txt
```

This will find all files that whose name match with the ones given in your `list.txt` in all sub-directories of the current directory and delete them.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for! Thank you so much